# Existem 'arrays' no JS, ou eles são apenas 'objetos disfarçados'?

Tags: javascript, array, objetos

Meu professor trouxe o questionamento atona, e ele dá bastante ênfase ao assunto. Afinal de contas, existem `array[]` de fato no *JavaScript* ou eles são meros objetos disfarçados? Como estou iniciando, gostaria de saber uma resposta concreta sobre.

Um dos argumentos utilizados para validar a tese por exemplo é o fato de você poder utilizar a conotação de array para trazer propriedades de um objeto. Exemplo:

```
var person = { nome: 'Fulano de Tal', idade: 37, altura: 1.85 };
```

Acima criei o objeto `person` e suas respectivas propriedades. Agora suponhamos que eu queira pegar a propriedade `nome` desse objeto, eu poderia fazer assim:

```
person.nome; // "Fulano de Tal"
```

Ou também posso chamar com a **conotação de array**:

```
person['nome']; // "Fulano de Tal"
```

Isso seria suficiente para afirmar que os arrays em javascript não passam de objetos camuflados? E qual o tamanho da relevância que isso pode ter no desenvolvimento de aplicações?